# How to debug EC2 DockerCompose crash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have a docker compose stack running on a ec2 t2.small. Every other week this whole thing crashes. I cannot connect to ssh though aws says the server is running. Nevertheless the website is down.

I checked the docker compose file: it should restart.
I checked the disk size, there ist no problem
I checked severals logs, all fine

Since I cannot connect to the server, when this is happening I have no idea how to debug and find the problem:

This is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: ..../nginx-docker:2.3.0
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx
    links:
      - ghost
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx/
    depends_on:
      - ghost
    networks:
      - app-network
  ghost:
    image: .../ghost-s3-adapter:5.33.6
    restart: always
    container_name: ghost
    volumes:
      - ${MOUNT_POINT}
      - ./logs/ghost:/logs/
    networks:
      - app-network
    environment:
      url: ${URL}
  pim:
    image: .../product-api:4.9.29
    restart: always
    container_name: pim
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - ./logs/spring:/logs
      - ./uploads:/data/uploads
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Can you scan the logs produced by the crashing container? You can easily filter it by using `cat logs.txt | grep "error"` to find what kind of errors are being thrown. You can also check the logs at the specific time when the container started crashing.

Comment: Yes I know but I did not find any error

Answer (score 2):

- Check the monitoring dashboards might be cpu or OOM(the basic monitoring does not have ram by default for ec2) on the box itself since it is a t2.small one; I would run it on a t2.medium/large and check if anything changes
- Configure and use the serial connection from the UI to use it when SSH fails.

Comment: Ah thanks the serial connection  is a good idea I didn't know it. I just have to wait not until it happens again :-(